# Weird problem with button clicking in a layout that has a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have run into a very strange problem. There is a layout I have with a RecyclerView and a button that switches on animation. The point is if I click the button right after the app executes - say 10 seconds, everything is fine. But if I leave the app running idle for some seconds, without touching anything, then when I click the button again, the animation simply doesn't start at all. And yet if after that I slide RecyclerView about the screen with my finger (in any place!) then the animation triggers all of a sudden. As if it was somehow frozen and "woke up" only after I interacted with the RecyclerView. As if RecyclerView after some seconds puts its animation-related objects to sleep somehow and they "wake-up" only after the RecyclerView is slided?.. Apparently the listener "goes to bed"... Is there a way to keep the animation-related objects "awake" at all times?

Here is the Animation function:

```
private void recyclerViewAnimate(final RecyclerView recyclerView, LayoutAnimationController controller) {
        if(isAnimating){
            return;
        }
        controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(recyclerView.getContext(), R.anim.layout_recycleview_disappear);
        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                                       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                           isAnimating = true;
                                           bt_add.animate().rotationXBy(180).setDuration(400).start();
                                           addButtonLayout.animate().setDuration(400).alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   addButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                                       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                           recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                           layoutSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                           layoutSettings.animate().scaleX(0.95f).setDuration(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   layoutSettings.animate().alpha(1)
                                                           .scaleY(1.01f).scaleX(1f).setDuration(400).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void run() {
                                                           settingsText.animate().setDuration(300).alpha(1).start();
                                                           isAnimating = false;
                                                          recyclerView.setLayoutAnimationListener(null);
                                                       }
                                                   }).start();
                                               }
                                           }).start();
                                       }
                                   });
        recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    }
```

Comment: Please post `layout_recycleview_disappear.xml` so I can help

Comment: You are setting the animation to the entire recyclerview, which means that the animation runs when the adapter changes or when the views are recycled while scrolling for example. If you want to animate a specific button in a specific item view, then you have to set those animations to the button itself.

Comment: Guys I solved the problem!
Instead of setting scheduleLayoutAnimation(); I needed to use startLayoutAnimation();
Apparently schedulrLayoutAnimation() function really only does stuff when you somehow interact with the RecyclerView, whereas startLayoutAnimation() executes it immediately upon request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `scheduleLayoutAnimation();` I needed to use `startLayoutAnimation();`